# No video preview image from DirectShow

Tags: .net, video, directshow, directshow.net, dpi-aware

I have an old .Net application that I wrote years ago that includes a video preview window. This uses a 3rd party library called DirectShowLib-2005.dll. My code is based on some example code I found online that I converted from c# to Vb.net. Basically it just sets up a simple capture graph and uses a SampleGrabber to link the video stream to a PictureBox control on a form.

This has been working fine with various users around the world, but recently we have had several new users who have reported that no image is displayed. At first we thought it might be an issue with camera drivers, but I can see that video data is coming through in the memory buffer.

It is difficult for me to debug as none of the machines I have access to show the problem. I do have one laptop that shows a slightly different problem. It does show an image but only part of the image is shown. Looks like it has been incorrectly centred. I discovered that changing the Text scaling in Windows display settings to 100% fixes this. This does not fix it for other users reporting the problem though, and they are seeing a grey background rather than a black background that I see.

My boss has the problem on his laptop PC. We have found that setting the Reduced Colour Mode in Compatibility Settings to 8-bit in the application shortcut properties fixes the problem for him.

I am trying to extract the essential part of the code into a separate test app so I can hopefully debug it a bit better, but I wondered if this is a known problem with modern PCs, or perhaps an issue with certain graphics cards or display drivers?

Thanks

Phil

Comment: Maybe you need to improve DPI awareness on the application itself to fix the scaling issues. This is directly related to text scaling, when system/monitor setting is not 100% OS  tries to fit the coordinates and the application might be getting wrong ones with one API but not the other and hence the mess. Also this would explain why turning on and off compatibility settings affects it. With fixed DPI awareness OS will do no or less tricks outside because it assumes the app handles it internally.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. The code has the dpi hard-coded as 24bpp I think. I did do a few tests trying to set different values, but it always seemed to be ignored and the images comes back at 24 anyway. I guess I need to delve deeper into the options in the directshow library.

Comment: No, no. DPI corresponds to that 100% of scaling. It's totally different from 24 bits/pixel. Applications indicating [high DPI awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms701681(v=vs.85)) notify that they know how to handle desktop settings other than 100%.

Comment: OK. So does the DirectShow library have a mechanism for me to specify this?

Comment: This is not really DirectShow problem and so DirectShow does not have and is not supposed to have a solution here. There could be a bugfix, possibly, in one of the DirectShow components but the API is at its end of life so this bugfix might not appear at all. You should be looking instead into [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows) and how to resolve the issue on this level (that is, by updating app manifest or programmatically).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess I need to do some more reading and searching. I didn't really want to spend a huge amount of time on this, as it is just a small part of a bigger program. It is embarrassing that some customers are unable to use the software on their new laptops though. 
Is there a better way nowadays to do image capture & preview in .Net? I am currently using VS2013 & .NET 4.0 but I do have access to later versions so could potentially upgrade the whole system, which is probably overdue anyway.