# How to preview and capture video in Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, winforms, video-capture

I have an old application that uses a DirectShow DLL for camera preview and image capture. This is just a small part of a bigger system. I have two issues. Firstly the [preview doesn't work for some users with modern High dpi graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272382/no-video-preview-image-from-directshow). Secondly the DLL is 32-bit forcing me to build the whole application as 32-bit.

I am currently using VS2013 and targetting .Net 4.0 but I do have the option to upgrade to newer versions if necessary.

With a bit more research I can probably find a way around the preview problems but I would really like to replace this with a better way of handling the camera data.

Any suggestions for the best / easiest way to do this?

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Have you thought about using [Emgu CV](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv) (or Open CV directly) to preview and  [capture video feeds](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.5/document/html/T_Emgu_CV_VideoCapture.htm)? -- See the example of CameraCapture, Video Surveillance and Face Detection there (yes, I know it's quite a big change, but it may address all issues)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a built-in DLL in Windows called `avicap32.dll`, which will let you show a live view from the webcam and capture from the webcam. [This tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/integrate-the-web-webcam-functionality-using-C-Sharp-net-and-com-part-viii/) explains it in further detail.

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Enjoy!